# Risk of Broadcast Receiver leak when registered in Application class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-application-class

I am registering a Broadcast Receiver in the app's Application class' `onCreate()`. I basically want the receiver to be active as long as the app's process is active. In this was, any component of the app getting triggered will result in the receivers getting automatically registered and won't be destroyed as long as the process is alive since I registered then in Application class.
**Application class**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "Registering broadcast receivers");
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        MyReceiver.register(context);
    }
```

**Broadcast Receiver class**:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static void register(final Context context) {
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("My Action");
        final  BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }
}
```

I have read in the documentation that in order to prevent receiver leak we should unregister the receiver in the corresponding lifecycle method of the one we are registering in. But the documentation talks about registering the receiver in `Activity` class. 
Does the same apply for registering the receiver in `Application` class ? The difference here seems that even when an activity is destroyed the app process is still active so the leak makes sense. But if I am registering in `Application` class, the only time I want my receiver to be unregistered is when the process is killed. Is there any possibility of a leak after the process is killed ?

Comment: yes, you are right. Normally the receiver should be unregistered. Based upon your requirement, you should handle it,

Comment: Always remember to call unregister receiver in onStop() of the activity.
If the broadcast Receiver is registered in onCreate(), then when the app goes into the background and resumed again, the receiver will not be registered again. So it is always good to register the broadcastReceiver in onStart() or onResume() of the activity and unregister in onStop().

Comment: Generally if you want that kind of behaviour than you should register your receivers and unregister them in a service which you launch on start of your application.

Comment: I am registering receiver in `Application` class not in `Activity` class. `Application` class does not provide `onDestroy()` callback so I am not sure how to handle it. I want to know are there any risks of not unregistering the broadcast registered in `Application` class?

Answer (score 1):

May be a solution that you can implement is the following:

Create a new class and implement `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.
The methods we are looking for are `onActivityPaused` and `onActivityResumed` so any other method can be empty.

Basically we want the broadcast receiver to **register** when activities (wichever activity) are on Resume and to **unregister** when activities are Paused.

The constructor of the class should have the reference to Application class and a reference to the broadcast receiver (you can pass them using dependency injection).

In this example I am checking network connection and there is an activity I don't want to register broadcast receiver (`ActivityDialog`)

```
class LifeCycleApplication(
    private val applicationReference: Application,
    private val networkReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
) : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity?) {
        if (activity !is ActivityDialog) {
            println("Broadcast down")
            applicationReference.unregisterReceiver(networkReceiver)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity?) {
        // on stop
    }

    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity?) {
        if (activity !is ActivityDialog) {
            println("Broadcast up")
            applicationReference.registerReceiver(networkReceiver, IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"))
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity?) {

    }
    ......
}
```

So every time an activity appears it register the broadcast receiver and when disappears the broadcast receiver is unregistered.

The Application class should look similar to:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    private var networkReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
    private lateinit var lcApplication: LifeCycleApplication

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        /** network connection in background **/
        networkReceiver = NetworkReceiver()
        lcApplication = LifeCycleApplication(this, networkReceiver!!)
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(lcApplication)
        ......
    }
    ......
}
```

Why this approach? Because the Application class only has `OnCreate` method.
For more information check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) of the android developers web page documentation.

I hope this can help you.